# Is it possible to implement interface IBus part of the NServiceBus framework?

Tags: nservicebus

In NServiceBus 3 it was possible to implement the `IBus` interface. After upgrading to NServiceBus 5 it no longer seems possible.

`IBus.InMemory` is a member of the `IBus` interface and has the type `IInMemoryOperations`. `IInMemoryOperations` is marked as obsolete.

Considering the conditions above, it does not seem possible to implement `IBus` since it has member of type, which is obsolete. Am I missing something?

Comment: to follow up on the answer below. i am simon.cropp on skype if u want to chat

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you have enabled warnings as errors enabled in your project?

You can disable that by disabling that specific compiler warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 618
    public IInMemoryOperations InMemory { get; }
#pragma warning restore 618
```

Answer (score 1):

The InMemory Bus functionality was removed in version 5 http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/4to5#inmemory-removal

So no it is not recommended that people implement it